# Dockerfile starting container failed: no file or directory

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to copy my binary file to the container and then execute it on container.

I have the swarm.exe in the same directory as Dockerfile. But I always get the same error: "./swarm: no such file or directory".

My dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.7-alpine


RUN echo http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community >> /etc/apk/repositories
RUN apk update && apk add --update openssl && apk add glide git
RUN mkdir /tools
WORKDIR /tools
RUN wget https://github.com/Masterminds/glide/releases/download/0.10.2/glide-0.10.2-linux-386.tar.gz
RUN tar -zxvf glide-0.10.2-linux-386.tar.gz
RUN mv linux-386/ glide/
ENV PATH /tools/glide:$PATH

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY swarm.exe .
CMD ["./swarm"]
```

Basically, I'm trying to copy swarm.exe to /usr/src/app (where I am now) and then execute ./swarm

Any ideas? 
Thanks

Comment: Can your user read `swarm.exe` ?

Answer (score 0):

[Alpine](https://alpinelinux.org/) images are linux based, they do not recognize `.exe` files like windows. Either do a `CMD ["./swarm.exe"]` or use a different image.

Comment: It also does not work. I think the problem is on COPY